# Using Fusion Chart in PHP and rendering in Smarty Templating Engine

Tags: php, web-applications, charts, smarty

My issue is not able to render the chart in .tpl file. The following code is the example taken from Fusion chart document check for [reference](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/docs/Contents/PHP_BasicExample.html)

```
<?php
   include("../Includes/FusionCharts.php");

   //Create an XML data document in a string variable
   $strXML  = "";
   $strXML .= "<graph caption='Monthly Unit Sales' xAxisName='Month' yAxisName='Units'
   decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0'>";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Jan' value='462' color='AFD8F8' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Feb' value='857' color='F6BD0F' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Mar' value='671' color='8BBA00' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Apr' value='494' color='FF8E46' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='May' value='761' color='008E8E' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Jun' value='960' color='D64646' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Jul' value='629' color='8E468E' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Aug' value='622' color='588526' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Sep' value='376' color='B3AA00' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Oct' value='494' color='008ED6' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Nov' value='761' color='9D080D' />";
   $strXML .= "<set name='Dec' value='960' color='A186BE' />";
   $strXML .= "</graph>";

   //Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data from strXML variable using dataXML method
   echo renderChartHTML("../../FusionCharts/FCF_Column3D.swf", "", $strXML, "myNext", 600, 300);
?>
```

It works if i render in normal .php but how to pass the renderChartHTML value to the Smarty tpl so that it will get displayed in a `<div>{$chartdata}</div>` like this .Would be great if any example to display Fusion chart in smarty tpl.

As of now i am able to get the graph like assigning the $strXML to smarty variable and passing the values directly to embed parameters. Anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

In PHP:

```
$smarty->assign('strXML', $strXML);
```

In .tpl :

```
<embed src="FCF_MSLine.swf" flashVars="&dataXML={$strXML}&chartWidth=900&chartHeight=600" quality="high" width="900" height="600" name="testgraph" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = renderChartHTML("../../FusionCharts/FCF_Column3D.swf", "", $strXML, "myNext", 600, 300);
$smarty->assign('chartdata', $output);
```